# Grunt.js task development production coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

**EDIT 2**: If using the following config (which is what appears to be natural setup), grunt doesn't compile any coffee files

```
coffee:
  development:
    compile:
      expand: true
      cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
      src: ["**/*.coffee"]
      dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
      ext: ".js"
    options:
      sourceMap:true
```

Grunt outputs the following when running with the -v flag
https://gist.github.com/mdedetrich/0ecccb50ddb2fd56dc35

**EDIT**: The relevant section now looks like this, and it appears to be working

```
coffee:
  development:
    expand: true
    cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
    src: ["**/*.coffee"]
    dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
    ext: ".js"
    options:
      sourceMap:true
  production:
    expand:true
    cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
    src: ["**/*.coffee"]
    dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
    ext: ".js"
```

However its somewhat confusing as to why its only working this way (and also why the compile section needs to be removed for it to work)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:

I am currently setting up a Gruntjs task, which looks like this

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig(
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")
    srcDir: "./src/main"
    srcDirLess: "<%= srcDir %>/less"
    srcDirCoffee: "<%= srcDir %>/coffee"
    scalaVersion: "scala-2.10" #This is the scala version we are using
    resourceManaged: "./target/<%= scalaVersion %>/resource_managed/main"
    cssOutput: "<%= resourceManaged %>/css"
    jsOutput: "<%= resourceManaged %>/js"
    cssRequestPath: "/css"
    jsRequestPath: "/js"

    less:
      development:
        options:
          paths: ["<%= srcDirLess %>"]
#          sourceMap:true
#          sourceMapFilename: "<%= cssOutput %>/index.css.map"
#          sourceMapRootpath: "<%= srcDirLess %>"
#          sourceMapURL:  "<%= cssRequestPath %>/index.css.map"
        files:
          "<%= cssOutput %>/index.css" : "<%= srcDirLess %>/index.less"
      production:
        options:
          paths: ['<%= srcDirLess %>']
          cleancss:true
        files:
          "<%= cssOutput %>/index.css" : "<%= srcDirLess %>/index.less"

    coffee:
      development:
        compile:
          files: [
            expand: true
            cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
            src: ["**/*.coffee"]
            dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
            ext: ".js"
          ]
#        options:
#          sourceMap:true
      production:
        compile:
          files: [
            expand:true
            cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
            src: ["**/*.coffee"]
            dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
            ext: ".js"
          ]

    requirejs:
      production:
        compile:
          options:
            baseUrl: "<%= jsOutput %>"
            mainConfigFile: "<%= jsOutput %>/main"

    watch:
      coffee:
        files: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>/**/*.coffee"
        tasks: ["coffee:development"]
      less:
        files: "<%= srcDirLess %>/**/*.less"
        tasks: ["less:development"]

    clean: ["<%= cssOutput %>","<%= jsOutput %>"]
  )

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs')
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean')

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee:development','less:development'])
  grunt.registerTask('production',['less:production','coffee:production','requirejs:production'])
```

Unfortunately for some reason, the `default` `coffee` task doesn't work properly (i.e. it doesn't actually run the task). If I take out the development/production sections in the coffee task, i.e.

```
    coffee:
#      development:
      compile:
        files: [
          expand: true
          cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
          src: ["**/*.coffee"]
          dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
          ext: ".js"
        ]
```

And change the default task to

```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee','less:development'])
```

It ends up working, does anyone know why this is happening? It works fine for `less`, but for some reason it doesn't with `coffee`

This is my package.json for the Grunt task

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: With `development` commented out, can you run `grunt coffee`, or is that only working as part of the default task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the task options in `file:[...]` is messing up your task.

Do this instead:

```
      compile:
        options:
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapDir: 'path/to/maps/' # source map files will be created here

        files:
          "<%= jsOutput %>": ["**/*.coffee"]
```

The git repo [explains](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) how to compile using such options in the `compileWithMapsDir` example.

```
compileWithMapsDir: {
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapDir: 'path/to/maps/' // source map files will be created here
    },
    files: {
      'path/to/result.js': 'path/to/source.coffee'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just removing the `file:[...]` part seems to have worked, however I have trouble understanding what exactly glob_to_multiple does (by itself it doesn't actually appear to compile any coffeescript)

Comment: Also note that using the `compile:` section doesn't work, see the edit I made in the original post I made

Comment: `glob_to_multiple` is the name they gave it because it takes any CoffeeScript file in the `cwd` of the source and complies all of them into separate js files is the `dest` directory. Ie. a glob a files to multiple ones. The `coffee` task tasks care of the compiling by default. In `glob_to_multiple` we're just adding extra options to get it to work by our preferences.

Comment: @mdedetrich whats wrong with the compile section, is it throwing an error?  did you  check to make sure the indentation was correct after the change? Try running it in verbose mode so we can see what went wrong: `grunt coffee -v`.

Comment: I think I am not communicating my issue, its no that your code doesn't work (it does), its getting it to work when you split out the tasks into sub tasks, in my case `production` and `development`. It appears that when doing this, you omit the `compile` option

I am not sure why this is the case, but its working fine as per EDIT 1. At this point I would just want an explanation as to why this is the case

Comment: If you check the grunt [docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) you'll see that the name compile doesn't matter. It could be named `foo`, `bar`, or anything else. the `coffee` task itself does the compiling, the target's named afterwards are just custom sub tasks that configure the *main* compiling task to your preferences.  It's only named compile in examples out of connivence.

Comment: Ah, that has answered my question completely, which is why I was confused. `compile` is just a placeholder, and it can be anything

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was confused with what the `compile` option means. In grunt.js, `compile` is just a placeholder, it doesn't actually mean anything, and is just used for documentation/demonstration reasons

The following version works fine and without any hassle

```
coffee:
  development:
    expand: true
    cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
    src: ["**/*.coffee"]
    dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
    ext: ".js"
    options:
      sourceMap:true
  production:
    expand:true
    cwd: "<%= srcDirCoffee %>"
    src: ["**/*.coffee"]
    dest: "<%= jsOutput %>"
    ext: ".js"
```